# Message/Folder permissions

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi

Is there a way to change folder and/or message permissions?
I noticed that folders created on root folder of a user, are not visible - is this a bug or a feature?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the detail steps and sample code how we can reproduce this issue? 

If you were developing with Office 365 REST API, there is no need to grant the special permission for the folder for the users retrieve the folders collection under the foot folder. The app only need “Mail.Read” scope. And we are able to get the folder collection via the REST below:
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders

Comment: I sent a POST request with: 
URL= https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/root/childfolders
content inside: {
  "DisplayName": "ExampleName"
}
The folder was created successfully, and reachable via API's. However it is not visible in the Outlook WebUI nor in the Outlook application. Is this by design?

Answer (score 0):

> > I sent a POST request with: URL= outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/root/childfolders content inside: { "DisplayName": "ExampleName" } The folder was created successfully, and reachable via API's. However it is not visible in the Outlook WebUI nor in the Outlook application. Is this by design? –

The end-point for the root folder is incorrect, there is no need to use the “root” keyword. And this end-point give the error when I try to create a folder.

Here is an sample to create a folder under the root folder for your reference:

```
POST: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders
```

Header:

```
authorization: bearer {token}
content-type: application/json
```

BODY:

```
{"DisplayName":"FolderName"}
```

And we will the 201 status code and response like figure below:
[image]